# Asbestos in old furniture adhesive?

Tags: adhesive, furniture, asbestos, table

I just bought a nice 1920s table which has obviously been fixed up a bit throughout its life, and thought I’d check before touching it whether there is any likelihood that the adhesive you can see in these photos could contain asbestos? I haven’t been able to find any authority on such things and I’m a bit paranoid. Any help appreciated!

[image: photo 1]
[image: photo 2]

Comment: Have a sample tested if it will make you sleep easier. Odds are strongly against...

Comment: Does any adhesive contain asbestos?  I cannot imagine why one would add asbestos to wood glue.

Comment: Blackjack floor tile adhesive often contained asbestos.  Not heard of its use in any other glue.  It's not a substitute for testing, but the internet is so full of money-chasing asbestos lawyers that if you can't find a reference to "asbestos in X" by searching, you're probably safe.  I'm paranoid but I wouldn't worry about wood glue.

Comment: The only way to be 100% certain that it does/does not contain asbestos is to have it tested. Chipping a sample off to take it to a lab will, potentially, expose you to about as much as chipping it off to replace it, so, as noted in George's [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/214150/34147), don't sweat it.

Comment: Not a definitive answer but based on the screw head I'd say that's a recent fix and the glue you can see there is probably gripfill or equivalent which is pretty modern. Does it have a sligh greenish tint to it?

Comment: Ive never heard of asbestos in glue. Its a silicate. A cousin of quarts. I dont see why they would add that to wood glue.

Comment: That is a yellow-zinc electroplated screw, not really common until after the 80s; asbestos was being phased out. Why you would want what is essentially glass in structural glue, I could never guess. I would worry about radon more than occasional low amount of exposure to asbestos, just do the work outside and wear a mask.

Answer (score 18):

As I've posted before, the risks of asbestos exposure on a very infrequent basis in a residential setting are highly over-blown. The real risks were for construction workers (pipe insulators, HVAC insulators, etc. ), back 50-60 years ago who where exposed to asbestos dust on a daily basis. I know the lawyers will hate me for saying this, but frankly asbestosis only occurred in an industrial setting not one off residential exposure to tiny amounts of asbestos.   It's not a poison, just an irritant that can lead to lung damage over a long period of time.  It's serious, but a one time exposure, probably very little, isn't anything to worry about.

Comment: I would just add that doing this restoration outside would all but eliminate any potential risk.

Comment: True, asbestosis is only caused by heavy and/or long-term exposure.  But mesothelioma can be caused by any exposure to asbestos, with no safe level.  Smaller exposures just give rise to smaller (but not zero) risks.  So in my book it is worth taking sensible precautions to reduce exposure.  Extreme precautions to reduce large exposures, smaller precautions to reduce smaller exposures.
Doing it outside *and wearing a mask* would be sensible (moreso for wood dust than the glue).

Comment: +100 for a thoughtful, reasoned answer that avoids media-induced fear and panic!

Comment: I should just add to this that tests have showed that a single asbestos fibre placed in a rat's lung can be sufficient to cause mesothelioma.

Comment: We all have masks anyway nowadays, so it's not like you have an excuse for not wearing one while working on a project that has the potential to generate small inhalable particles. :) (It's a joke, please don't correct me on whether a COVID mask is suitable for such or not.)

Comment: @aucuparia  Thank you for contributing.  I did not know that.   I'm pretty careful around sanding dust as well. I have one of those large JET air purifiers in my shop as well as an Oneida dust collector. Next on my list is a downdraft sanding table.  Thanks again.

Comment: Not just construction workers though, I know of multiple cases where the handyman of a hotel got asbestos cancer from working with it every so often for years. Still not remotely what the average enthusiast will reach, not in this day and age, but you don't need 40h a week 40 years exposure either.

Comment: Agree with most  comments here that reasonable cautions need to be taken:  masks, dust collection, working outside, etc.  But the hysteria is unwarranted.   Oftentimes containment results in a better outcome than removal.   But when that's not possible due to remodel or building changes and you need to remove asbestos insulation, old floor tiles, sheetrock with mud containing asbestos (used up to the mid-70s) YES, then mitigation and proper disposal is important. Just keep everything in perspective.

Comment: Asbestos is a fiber. What you have here is a translucent adhesive. Not a chance. In addition to the good points from the answer. It was also used for its insulation (heat and electrical) properties. No point wasting fancy expensive asbestos to join pieces of wood.